# Establecer tiempo de duración de una sesión

Tags: php

estoy realizando un inicio de sesión en el cual es obligatorio que el campo Mantenerme Conectado este presente, y que al usuario presionar el checkbox y envie los datos su sesión se mantenga iniciada por un tiempo de 3 dias, y en caso contrario que solo dure un dia. Lo estoy realizando de la siguiente forma:

```
<input name="sesion" type="checkbox" id="signed-in"/>
<label for="signed-in">Mantenerme Conectado</label>

if(!empty($_POST['sesion'])){ 
 ini_set('session.cookie_lifetime', time() + (60*60*72)); 
} else {
 ini_set('session.cookie_lifetime', time() + (60*60*24)); 
}
```

El problema que me esta arrojando es este:

```
Warning:  ini_set(): A session is active. You cannot change the session module's ini settings at this time in line 17
```

Ahora no se si es porque antes de eso tengo el session_start declarado, de verdad no lo se. O si hay alguna mejor forma de mantener la sesión iniciada agradeceria mucho de vuestra ayuda. Gracias

Answer (score 2, accepted):

Estás haciendo un set de una directiva de configuración. Lo que necesitarías es hacer un set de la *cookie* de sesión. Para ello puedes usar *session_set_cookie_params()* donde el primer argumento es el tiempo de vida.

Antes de seguir, dos notas:

1. Intenta que toda la lógica esté en la parte superior y no mezclada con *html*, que te puede dar más problemas que beneficios.
2. El tiempo de vida es en segundos a partir del momento en que se crea. `time() + (60*60*24)` te dará un tiempo de vida hasta el 2066 (*en el momento de escribir la respuesta*).

Prueba con algo de este estilo:

```
if(!empty($_POST['sesion'])) {
    // $ttl = strtotime('+3 day') - time(); # otra forma de hacerlo
    $ttl = 60 * 60 * 72;
}
else {
    // $ttl = strtotime('+1 day') - time(); # otra forma de hacerlo
    $ttl = 60 * 60 * 24;
}
session_set_cookie_params($ttl); # set del tiempo de vida
session_name('test_session'); # por si quieres cambiar el nombre de la cookie
session_start(); # inicias la sesión
```

**Como nota adicional**, *session_set_cookie_params()* no hace el set del tiempo de vida si ya hay una sesión creada. Por lo tanto, si se ha iniciado una sesión antes de que se seleccione y se envíe lo de *Mantenerme conectado*, no hará efecto el cambio del tiempo de vida. Tendrías que, o no inicial sesión hasta enviar este formulario, o eliminar la sesión actual y volver a crear una nueva con los nuevos datos de vida de la sesión.

## EDITO

Si tienes un archivo externo para iniciar la sesión solo hay que modificar un poco el planteamiento.

El inicio de sesión hace el set por defecto del tiempo de vida (*ttl*)...

```
// ----- archivo externo -------
$ttl = (60 * 60 * 24);
session_set_cookie_params($ttl);
session_start();
// -----------------------------
```

... y si se autoriza la nueva sesión se hace el set del nuevo *ttl*.

```
if(!empty($_POST['sesion'])) {
    $ttl = (60 * 60 * 72);
    session_write_close();
    session_set_cookie_params($ttl);
    session_start();
    // opcional, regenerar el id de sesión y eliminar la sesión anterior
    session_regenerate_id(true);
    /**
     * Puedes redirigir directamente a otra parte del sitio
     * IMPORTANTE: Entre el inicio de ejecución y esta línea
     *             no debe existir ninguna salida de html
     */
    header('Location: /');
}
```

Comment: Gracias Oscar, he probado con tu respuesta, y me esta mostrando esto por console session_set_cookie_params(): Cannot change session cookie parameters when session is active, me olvide en comentar que el session_start() lo tengo en un archivo externo el cual esta incluido en todo mi proyecto de manera general. No se si me esta pasando esto por que el session_start() esta arriba del session_set_cookie_params(), o no hay problema con eso?

Comment: @AlejoMendoza He editado la respuesta a raíz del comentario. A ver que tal con este planteamiento.

Comment: Saludos @OscarR, al parecer a funcionado bien. Gracias por al respuesta!